# Как создать окно, которое невозможно свернуть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
#тут должна быть строка кода, которая делает окно не сворачиваемым можно в ответ писать только это строку кода без остальных
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну с огромным костылем, но обычным `bind` можно сделать это с главным окном

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

root.bind('<Unmap>', lambda event: event.widget.deiconify())
root.mainloop()
```

или при помощи `transient()` можно убрать панель сворачивания

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Toplevel
root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()
Legend = Label(top, text="Модальный диалог")
Legend.pack()
top.transient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]