# Как в tkinter запретить нажимать на кнопки свернуть\развернуть

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как можно сделать чтобы кнопка `свернуть\развернуть` не работала в окне *tkinter* ?

Работаю на Python 3.8 в редакторе Python Idle

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать окно, которое невозможно свернуть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840410/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Windows вы можете использовать атрибут - `toolwindow`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]